# Does firebase use any kind of nosql database behind the scene like MongoDB?What backend technology enables firebase?

Tags: mongodb, firebase

As far as I know the database  model of the firebase is key value storage model. As from the documents i have seen so far the database implementation is specific to firebase but I found some comments on quora that it stores data in MongoDB but did not find the clear answer, but was not sure.
http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-backend-technologies-that-enable-Firebase

Does it still use MongoDB to store its data I found no such documentation in firebase website.Was it using it previosly but does not use it now. What kind of backend technology is used by firebase for data storage and for its querying capabilities now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems its been unanswered. As far as I have known Firebase uses MongoDB as backend it said so when it was first released ..Not sure if they changed it later..Should be the same I belive... I was looking for answer while i was looking for ways to monitoring the cloud db services like firebase and mongolab to look at their API's